# the multi-part identifier SIV_DB_PreProd.dbo.SIV_SuperVision.ReservationSabilId could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I am having a very big trouble with this error. i am trying to insert into a table from the result of a select and i am having this error that i don't understand...

```
    INSERT INTO SIV_DB_PreProd.dbo.SIV_SuperVision  
        SELECT 

        HRC.ID_Reservation [ReservationSabilId]
        ,null [ConfigurationPlaceId]
        ,HRC.NUMERO_PLACE [NumeroPlace]
        ,HRC.NUMERO_COMPARTIMENT [NumeroCompartiment]
        ,HRC.CODE_TRAIN_AUTOCAR [NumeroCirculation]
        ,HRC.DATE_TRAIN [DateCirculation]
        ,(case HRC.CODE_CONFORT when 1 then 1 when 2 then 2 end) [CodeConfort]
        ,DATE_ETAT [DateReservation]
        ,1 [IsSabilToSIV]
        ,0 [StatutSuperVision]  


      FROM [dbo].RESERVATION_PLACE_CENTRAL HRC inner join HISTORIQUE_RESERVATION_CENTRAL
      on hrc.ID_RESERVATION= HISTORIQUE_RESERVATION_CENTRAL.ID_RESERVATION
      where  DATEDIFF(MM, DATE_ETAT , getdate())=0
      and hrc.NUMERO_EMETTEUR>0 and hrc.ETAT_RESERVATION in (''R'')
      and ( hrc.ID_RESERVATION <> SIV_DB_PreProd.dbo.SIV_SuperVision.ReservationSabilId 
            or (hrc.ID_RESERVATION = SIV_DB_PreProd.dbo.SIV_SuperVision.ReservationSabilId
                and SIV_DB_PreProd.dbo.SIV_SuperVision.StatutSuperVision = 0)
          )
```

Comment: Can you run the select stand-alone?

Comment: I just tried it give me the same message

Comment: Where is table `dbo.SIV_SuperVision` in JOINING logic

Comment: could you guys give me some help i don't really know how to use two join in one select statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INSERT INTO SIV_DB_PreProd.dbo.SIV_SuperVision
        SELECT

```
    HRC.ID_Reservation [ReservationSabilId]
    ,null [ConfigurationPlaceId]
    ,HRC.NUMERO_PLACE [NumeroPlace]
    ,HRC.NUMERO_COMPARTIMENT [NumeroCompartiment]
    ,HRC.CODE_TRAIN_AUTOCAR [NumeroCirculation]
    ,HRC.DATE_TRAIN [DateCirculation]
    ,(case HRC.CODE_CONFORT when 1 then 1 when 2 then 2 end) [CodeConfort]
    ,DATE_ETAT [DateReservation]
    ,1 [IsSabilToSIV]
    ,0 [StatutSuperVision]  


  FROM [dbo].RESERVATION_PLACE_CENTRAL HRC 

  inner join HISTORIQUE_RESERVATION_CENTRAL
  on hrc.ID_RESERVATION= HISTORIQUE_RESERVATION_CENTRAL.ID_RESERVATION

  inner join SIV_DB_PreProd.dbo.SIV_SuperVision SV
    on hrc.ID_RESERVATION=SV.ReservationSabilId

     where  DATEDIFF(MM, DATE_ETAT , getdate())=0
    and hrc.NUMERO_EMETTEUR>0 and hrc.ETAT_RESERVATION in (''R'')
     and ( hrc.ID_RESERVATION <> SIV_DB_PreProd.dbo.SIV_SuperVision.ReservationSabilId 
        or (hrc.ID_RESERVATION = SIV_DB_PreProd.dbo.SIV_SuperVision.ReservationSabilId
            and SIV_DB_PreProd.dbo.SIV_SuperVision.StatutSuperVision = 0)
      )
```

Comment: the SIV_DB_PreProd.dbo.SIV_SuperVision is in an other database (SIV_DB_PreProd) ... but the first two in the join in different one (Sabil_DB) could i still join and how ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use **SIV_DB_PreProd.dbo.SIV_SuperVision** table without making join on it. 
If I get your query purpose correctly, better you should go for [MERGE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx).

```
INSERT INTO SIV_DB_PreProd.dbo.SIV_SuperVision  
        SELECT 

        HRC.ID_Reservation [ReservationSabilId]
        ,null [ConfigurationPlaceId]
        ,HRC.NUMERO_PLACE [NumeroPlace]
        ,HRC.NUMERO_COMPARTIMENT [NumeroCompartiment]
        ,HRC.CODE_TRAIN_AUTOCAR [NumeroCirculation]
        ,HRC.DATE_TRAIN [DateCirculation]
        ,(case HRC.CODE_CONFORT when 1 then 1 when 2 then 2 end) [CodeConfort]
        ,DATE_ETAT [DateReservation]
        ,1 [IsSabilToSIV]
        ,0 [StatutSuperVision]  


      FROM [dbo].RESERVATION_PLACE_CENTRAL HRC inner join HISTORIQUE_RESERVATION_CENTRAL
      on hrc.ID_RESERVATION= HISTORIQUE_RESERVATION_CENTRAL.ID_RESERVATION
      INNER JOIN SIV_DB_PreProd.dbo.SIV_SuperVision SIV ON SIV.ReservationSabilId <> hrc.ID_RESERVATION or (hrc.ID_RESERVATION = SIV.ReservationSabilId
                and SIV.StatutSuperVision = 0)
      where  DATEDIFF(MM, DATE_ETAT , getdate())=0
      and hrc.NUMERO_EMETTEUR>0 and hrc.ETAT_RESERVATION in (''R'')
```

Comment: the SIV_DB_PreProd.dbo.SIV_SuperVision  is in an other database (SIV_DB_PreProd) ... but the first two in the join in different one (Sabil_DB) could i still join and how ?